# MvxFullBinding not updating on MainThread

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

With MvvmCross 3.5.1, I've found that when using MvxFullBinding in the android layout binding description, the UpdateTargetFromSource method is not called on the MainThread.
Is this on purpose? I was thinking that it will behave the same as on RaisePropertyChanged.

Given a full binding like this:

```
<TextView
   style="@style/ValueText"
   local:MvxBind="Text SelectedObject.Name" />
```

And the view model containing the selected object:

```
public IMyObject SelectedObject { get; }
```

Where the selected object implements the INotifyPropertyChanged.
If the `Name` property change is notified from another thread in the application, the update will not be effective and `MainThread` exception will be thrown : `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Thanks for the help, and Long Life to MvvmCross :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the job of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation to put notifications onto the UI thread

The `MvxViewModel` and `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` classes do this automatically for you - but if you implement your own `INotifyPropertyChanged` classes, then you'll need to make sure `PropertyChanged` is raised on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I understand the purpose to not doing it the same way as in RaisePropertyChanged, as it's INotifyPropertyChanged specific implementation role. The only thing is that the most of my Model is whithin PCL layers that do not have facilities to invoke the InvokeOnMainThread. In addition to the fact that we were migrating the whole app from the vNext version, where the FullBinding was not working properly. Anyway, thanks for the update

Comment: You can use Mvx to marshal calls on to the UI thread - request the IMvxMainThreadDispatcher - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Core/IMvxMainThreadDispatcher.cs